# How to make multiple "for" statements run efficiently in VBA

Tags: vba, for-loop, row

In my code there is a searching order and it does as folloing:

It takes each value (about 2000 ranges) in ws.sheet range A and looks it up in another sheet named wp.sheet range A (about 90 ranges). If a particular value x in ws.sheet range e.g A3 is not found in wp.sheet range A the next search order in sheet ws.sheet is the value y in the next range B3 (same row as value x) to be searched in sheet wp.sheet in the entire range B, and so on.

This is what my "for" loop does and the issue with my code is that it takes very long as it compares each value in ws.sheet range A1-2000 to the values in wp.sheet range A1-90. Is there an alternative which does it more quickly or more efficiently?

```
Dim wb As Workbook, wq As Object
Dim ws, wi As Worksheet, datDatum
Dim w As Long, I As Long, t As Long
Dim DefaultMsgBox()
Dim r, i As Integer    



For r = 2 To 2000

Check = True:

For i = 1 To 90
    If ws.Range("A" & r).Value = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range("A" & i).Value Then
       wp.Sheets("ABC").Rows(i).Columns("E:AB").Copy
       ws.Range("G" & r).PasteSpecial
       GoTo NextR
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 90
     If ws.Range("B" & r).Value = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range("B" & i).Value Then
        wp.Sheets("ABC").Rows(i).Columns("E:AB").Copy
        ws.Range("G" & r).PasteSpecial
        GoTo NextR
     End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 90
     If ws.Range("C" & r).Value = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range("C" & i).Value And ws.Range("D" & r).Value = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range("D" & i).Value Then
        wp.Sheets("ABC").Rows(i).Columns("E:AB").Copy
        ws.Range("G" & r).PasteSpecial
        GoTo NextR
     End If
 Next i

NextR:
    If Not Check = ws.Range("A" & r).Value = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range("A" & i).Value Or Not Check = ws.Range("B" & r).Value = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range("A" & i).Value Or Not Check = ws.Range("C" & r).Value = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range("C" & i).Value And ws.Range("D" & r).Value = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range("D" & i).Value Then
    MsgBox "......"
    End If
Next r
End sub
```

Comment: Is it required that the value has to be searched for in column A before column B? Are Columns C & D supposed to be checked together, or was that from experimenting with combining the conditions? Is the `.Copy` supposed to be doing anything, or is that being used with a later paste?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I have added the paste command as well. I had excluded it as it wasnt necessary. The order in which the searching is being done is fixed, it has got a purppose

Comment: Why "Next ru"? Should be "Next i"

Comment: Thats right, i have corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest turning off ScreenUpdating and using the Find function instead:

```
Dim cell, foundValue, lookupRange As Range

Set wp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABC")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WS")

r = 2
number_r = 2000
ru = 1
number_ru = 90

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop through each cell in WS, offsetting through columns A to C
For Each cell In ws.Range("A" & r & ":A" & number_r)
    For i = 0 To 2

        'Define range to look up in ABC
        Set lookupRange = wp.Range(wp.Cells(ru, i + 1), wp.Cells(number_ru, i + 1))

        'Look for current WS cell on corresponding column in ABC
        Set foundValue = lookupRange.Find(cell.Offset(0, i).Value)

        'If cell is found in ABC...
        If Not foundValue Is Nothing Then
            Select Case i
            Case 2 'If found cell is in column C

                Do 'Lookup loop start

                'If same values on columns D...
                If foundValue.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value Then

                    'Copy data to WS and switch to the next cell
                    wp.Rows(foundValue.Row).Columns("E:AB").Copy
                    ws.Range("G" & cell.Row).PasteSpecial
                    GoTo nextCell

                'If not same values on columns D...
                Else

                    'Try to find next match, if any
                    Set foundValue = lookupRange.FindNext(foundValue)
                    If foundValue Is Nothing Then GoTo noMatchFound

                End If

                Loop 'Repeat until WS values in column C and D match ABC values in columns C and D

            Case Else 'If found cell is in column A or B

                'Copy data to WS and switch to the next cell
                wp.Rows(foundValue.Row).Columns("E:AB").Copy
                ws.Range("G" & cell.Row).PasteSpecial
                GoTo nextCell

            End Select

        End If
    Next i
noMatchFound:
    MsgBox "......" 'Message appears only when no match was found in column A, column B and column C + D
nextCell:
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Hi Chavez, thank you for your support. I will tried it out right away

Comment: Hi Chavez, the code isnt quite what I was looking for. In your code when the value in range (A r) is found in sheet ABC range(A i) it jumps to the next colums B and carries on with the search. But my intention is rather: take value in range (A2) of sheet "ws" and look it up in sheet ABC range (A). If A2 is found in sheet ABC range A, all good. If it is not found, jumps to B2 in sheet "ws" and look for that value in sheet ABC range B and so on. This is what my "for" loop states. However, it takes very long as it goes through all the ranges. I will edit my text further to make it clearer

Comment: Hi Yavuz, I modified the code based on your clarification. I also turned off ScreenUpdating to try to make the code run faster. Let me know if this works as you initially expected.

Comment: Hi Chavez thank you very much for your effort. I have tried the code out with some samples and it seems to work very well. Though one more thing, would it also be possible to include in the "find" part  an additional code which, after looking and comparing the values columns A and B in both sheets, it takes not only column C but takes the values in column C and D together and compares it with the columns C and D in the other sheet. ANd the condition is that both values have to be identical in boths sheets. I am thinking about the " Application.Match" function. Would that be suitable for it?

Comment: Hello Yavuz. Sorry for the late reply. I forgot about the condition for columns C + D. I've added it now. Please let me know if this is working as you expected and if you have any question.

Comment: hi chavez, thank you very much for your effort. In the meantime I had found a solution, butyour is much faster and better readable.Thank you very much for that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't mind my saying so, but your code is hard to follow, including your choice of variable names. I can recommend that if you do not make use of your .copy statements, then comment them out and your code will run much faster.

Comment: Hi jay, thank you for your comment. I have tried to simplified the choice of my variables a bit. I hope it is a bit clearer now.